# Making the <header> tag disabled using CSS without Hiding

Tags: css, html, http-headers

How to make the `<header>` disabled using CSS without hiding it?
I don't see any **disabled** attribute that can add to the element. I have some dropdowns and button in the header tag.

When I wanted to disable the whole page. I added a div with a class using JQuery.

```
<div class="modalOverlay"></div>
```

And the CSS style is

```
.modalOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right:0%;
    bottom : 0%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* black semi-transparent */
}
```

The style is applying to the whole page except the elements in header tag. How do I disable those? Probably with CSS so I can just add a class and remove it when necessary.

**UPDATE:**

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Title </a> <a
            class="toggle-nav btn pull-left" href=""> <i class="icon-reorder"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown medium only-icon widget"><a
                class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> <i
                    class="icon-rss"></i>
                    <div class="label">1</div>
            </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="widget-body">
                                <div class="pull-left icon">
                                    <i class="icon-user text-success"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left text">
                                    New User Added. <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="widget-footer"><a href="">All notifications</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="dropdown dark user-menu"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> <img width="23" height="23"
                    alt="userName" src="assets/images/male_icon.png" />
                    <span class="user-name">Hi, Guest</span> <b
                    class="caret"></b>
            </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href=""> <i class="icon-user"></i> Profile
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> <i class="icon-cog"></i> Settings
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="" ng-click="logout()"> <i
                            class="icon-signout"></i> Sign out
                    </a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `header` element in the code example. It is unclear what is meant by disabling something; CSS generally does not disable functionality.

Comment: In the header tag I have some links and buttons which I want to disable. I have mentioned that in the question. So what's unclear? I have added the HTML also for you to understand.

Comment: If “disabling” means that elements do not have their normal HTML functionality, then the answer is “You can’t, CSS is not for such things.” The title is rather misleading, since the `header` element itself has no HTML functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `pointer-events:none;` in this case the text should be visible but the content inside `div` and evel `<a>` won't work. Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/feruceri/1/edit)**.

```
.modalOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right:0%;
    bottom : 0%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* black semi-transparent */
 pointer-events:none; /*This is the KEY*/
}
```

Comment: The `pointer-events` property, when it works, affects pointer events only. It does not prevent the use of links, buttons, and dropdowns with the keyboard.

Comment: Applying `pointer-events:none;` to this class will not work. instead the other elements or links also was working when I added as per your answer. But i added the style alone to header tag when adding the div to body also. That time it got worked :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try "z-index:99"

```
.modalOverlay {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 right:0%;
 bottom : 0%;
 z-index:99;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* black semi-transparent */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.modalOverlay {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable elements in CSS, in the sense of removing their functionality as defined in HTML or as programmed with JavaScript. Most attempts at doing so will affect at most mouse operations, not keyboard-based (or speech-based) use of controls and links.

The proper way to disable a control in HTML is to set the [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls%3a-the-disabled-attribute) attribute or property on it, in HTML or in JavaScript. For a link, you need to remove the `href` property (and, if desired, you can save its value e.g. to a `data-href` property so that it can be restored). To do this for all controls and links inside an element, you need some JavaScript code that traverses the descendants of the element.

Comment: I applied `pointer-events:none;` to the header tag and it got worked for me.

Comment: @ShijuKBabu, I take it so that you did not test what happens when you use the page with the keyboard, e.g. using the TAB key to move to a link or button and the Enter key to follow a link or activate the button.